# knitr: fig.height must be numeric in new version?

Tags: latex, knitr, rnw

I downloaded a new version of the knitr package and suddenly I get the following error when trying to include a plot in an Rnw file:

```
Error in options[[sprintf("fig.%s", i)]] * options$dpi : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
Calls: knit ... process_group.block -> call_block -> fix_options -> %n%
```

After a lot of experimenting I found out the problem is with the command fig.height, apparently it is supposed to be numeric. This code produces the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<cat, fig.cap="dog", fig.height='\\textheight'>>=
plot(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 1, 3))
@

\end{document}
```

This code does not:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<cat, fig.cap="dog", fig.height=6>>=
plot(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 1, 3))
@

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what the unit of measurement for this 6 is.

This code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<cat, fig.cap="dog", fig.height=6cm>>=
plot(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 1, 3))
@

\end{document}
```

produces a different error:

```
Error in base::parse(text = code, srcfile = NULL) : 
  1:44: unexpected symbol
1: alist( 'cat', fig.cap="dog", fig.height=6cm
                                           ^
Calls: knit ... withCallingHandlers -> eval -> parse_only -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

All in all it seems as if knitr is really expecting a numeric value for fig.height, which is moderately annoying because I have already typed a lot of `fig.height='\\textheight'` commands throughout my document (back in the days that that still worked) and I also do not really know what the numeric value corresponding to Latex's `\textheight` is.

Any advise?

UPDATE: I did some more experimenting and it turns out that the numbers you feed to fig.height appear nowhere in the Latex-file, instead they influence the dimension of the cat.pdf image produced by knitr directly. This kind of suggest that leaving out `fig.height` altogether might be the best strategy. Still this doesn't tell us how to get the `[height=\textheight]` in the tex document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the chunk option `out.height` instead of `fig.height`.